# Tap Event Handler doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I want to use the tap option for my app, but I can't get it work...

**XAML**

```
<Rectangle Name="rectangle4" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Canvas Name="currentPanel" Tap="currentPanel_Tap" >
    <Rectangle Name="rectangle3" Visibility="Visible" />
    <TextBlock Name="currentBlock" Visibility="Visible" />
    <Image Name="image7" Visibility="Visible" />
</Canvas>
<StackPanel Name="optionsPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBlock Name="option1Block" />
    <TextBlock Name="option2Block" />
    <TextBlock Name="option3Block" />
    <TextBlock Name="option4Block" />
    <TextBlock Name="option5Block" />
    <TextBlock Name="option6Block" />
</StackPanel>
```

**CODE**

```
private void currentPanel_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        optionsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        image7.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyApp;component/Images/Small/drop%20down.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

When tap on the content of the canvas nothing happens... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, putting a breakpoint at the start of currentPanel_Tap?

Comment: Dumping all xaml (e.g., every margin, height, alignment, etc property) makes it *exceedingly difficult* to see what's going on.  In future, try trimming that out before posting.  Formatting everything so it sits within the question helps people to parse it easier.  The easier you make it for us the more likely it is we can sort out your issue!  Your problem is probably not even included in all that xaml.  I'd wager you have your rectangle, canvas and stack panel all within  a Grid (the parent of all three). The StackPanel is the only control getting input events as it is the topmost.  Amirite?

Comment: Can you show more of your XAML page. If I drop the above in a StackPanel the Canvas is not visible (as it has no size) and so cannot be tapped.